# sqlcmd syntax issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I am trying to run some sqlcmd to create new database on a new server but everytime I run my script I get the incorrect syntax near 'S' and do not know why exactly. the command line is to create a new databse from scripts
this is the line in question: sqlcmd -S SSO-SRVTEST -d TEST -i "C:\TEST\1_CreateDb.sql"
This is the script I use to create and exec the command line

```
SET @Command = 'DIR /B /O:-N ' + @ScriptFilesDir + '*.sql';
INSERT INTO @FileList (FileName) EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command; 
DELETE FROM @FileList WHERE FileName IS NULL OR FileName NOT LIKE '%.sql';
DELETE FROM @FileList WHERE LEFT(FILENAME,1) = '_';

UPDATE @FileList SET Command = 'sqlcmd -S ' + @ServerName 
                         + ' -d ' + @DbName + ' -i "' + @ScriptFilesDir + FileName 
                         + '" >> ' + @ScriptFilesDir + 'Output.txt';

--select * from @FileList
-- Run the script files one by one on each of the specified databases 
PRINT 'Running Scripts...'

SELECT @FileNumber = MAX(FileNumber) FROM @FileList; 
WHILE (@FileNumber > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @FileNumber = @FileNumber - 1, @FileName = FileName, @Command = Command 
    FROM @FileList 
    WHERE FileNumber = @FileNumber; 
    
    RAISERROR ('    Executing file %s',0, 1, @FileName) WITH NOWAIT

    SET @Command1 = 'ECHO ' + @FileName + ': >> ' + @ScriptFilesDir + 'Output.txt';
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command1, NO_OUTPUT;

    SET @Command1 = REPLACE(@Command, '%DATABASE%', @DBName);
    PRINT @Command1
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command1, NO_OUTPUT;
END
PRINT 'Running Scripts Complete'
```

basically this script goes thru some scripts to create the db, views, sp, functions, index ect..
this script is executre from SSMS
why am I getting this error ?

Thanks

Comment: You have a dash in your server name, which is a parameter character being parsed by the command line. Enclose your server name in quotes and try again.

Comment: comment out the execution lines and see what's wrong with the printed commands by individually running those in a separate session. You will definitely get an idea which part is causing the issue.